# Add selected text from a dropdown to an href -then remove what was added before changing the href again

Tags: jquery

So far I have code that will add the selected text to an href :

```
    $('select#statFilter').change(function () {

    //get the item selected in the dropdown
    var Myval = $("select#statFilter option:selected").text();
    //add it to the specifi url:
     $('a.add.addval').attr('href', $('a.add.addval').attr('href')+Myval);

  }
```

it works, however, if I keep making selections, the href keeps being added to -what I want is for it to clear what I just added and append the href with the new selection:

I tried this to check if the href has the word 'Active' for example and it won't work:

```
if($('a.add.addval').attr('href', $('a.add.addval').attr('href'):contains('Active')){
    $('a.add.addval').attr('href', $('a.add.addval').attr('href').replace('Active','')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your code is like that. You need to keep the initial value in an external variable and append to that. Now you are appending to whatever is in the same href attribute. This is logic error.

```
var initValue=null;

$('select#statFilter').change(function () {    
    if(initValue==null)
       initValue=$('a.add.addval').attr('href');

    //get the item selected in the dropdown
    var Myval = $("select#statFilter option:selected").text();
    //add it to the specifi url:
     $('a.add.addval').attr('href', initValue+Myval);

}
```

Comment: I just added the parens that were missing in the if statement and it works like a charm! THANK YOU!